# Not able to print correct confusion matrix and also in heatmap values are printing in example 2e+2, e+4 etc etc

Tags: python-3.x, keras, heatmap, confusion-matrix

Not able to print confusion matrix correctly and also the in printing heatmap the values in some blocks or columns are printing in example 2e+2,e+4 etc etc. Please help me in this

import numpy as np 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    import pandas as pd
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Convolution2D
    from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
    from keras.layers import Flatten
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

```
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))


classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))


# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 10, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.4,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

#importing training data

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('Dataset/train',
                                                 target_size = (64,64),
                                                 batch_size = 64,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

#importing test data
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('Dataset/test',target_size = (64,64),
                                            batch_size = 64,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical',shuffle=False)

#storing all the history

history = classifier.fit_generator(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=20,
        epochs=5,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=2000)
print(history.history.keys())
```

#summarize accuracy

```
plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

#Confution Matrix 
Y_pred = classifier.predict_generator(test_set, steps=len(test_set), max_queue_size=10, workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False, verbose=0)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)

#assigning values 
confusion=(confusion_matrix(test_set.classes, y_pred))
confusion_df = pd.DataFrame(confusion,
                     index = ['Airplan','Car','Birds','Cats','Deer', 'Dogs','Frog', 'Horse','Ship','Truck'], 
                     columns = ['Airplan','Car','Birds','Cats','Deer', 'Dogs','Frog', 'Horse','Ship','Truck'])

#heatmap    
sns.heatmap(confusion_df, annot=True)
print(confusion_df)

#classification report
print('Classification Report')
target_names = ['Airplan','Car','Birds','Cats','Deer', 'Dogs','Frog', 'Horse','Ship','Truck']
print(classification_report(test_set.classes, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
```

Comment: "Not able to print confusion matrix correctly " could you explain this better? Show error logs if any.

Comment: @Anakin the confusion matrix is not printed correctly means the diagonal elements are not filled properly but complete matrix filled with numbers.

Comment: Please post output matrix. Also please explain what is actual result v/s what is expected.

Comment: @Hitsa confusion matrix means how many images the system recognize correctly of a particular category i.e the diagonal should be filled with maximum values and the blocks should be left having values like 0 or 1.But in code the output matrix is completely filled with different values ....i.e. the diagonal filling is not highlighted.

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try this.

```
sns.heatmap(confusion_df, annot=True, fmt='.2f')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume  that your confusion matrix is cm

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn  as  sns

cm = np.array([[345,12],[0,104763]])

plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
sns.heatmap(cm,annot=True,linewidths=1, fmt = 'd')
plt.xlabel('predicted')
plt.ylabel('Truth')
plt.show()
```

you'll get the  below  matrix:

[image]